# What does "even the keel in favour of " in the sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, american-english, sentence, subcontinental-english

Even the legal framework that is supposed to provide a modicum of protection to workers is fraying. For instance, the state’s unwillingness to use the provisions of the Industrial Disputes Act or the Contract Labour (Regulation and Abolition) Act to even the keel in favour of labour even during serious episodes of labour unrest has been a recurrent feature of the state’s conduct in this period.

Comment: In my opinion, the intended meaning is 'redress the balance so as to give the workers a fair deal', but it sounds like a misusage to me. And the number of Google hits for “even the keel in favour of ” seems like substantiating evidence.

Comment: It's a non-standard "bending" of the idiomatically standard [*on an even keel*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+an+even+keel) *(calm and not likely to change suddenly My main priority is to keep my life on an even keel for the sake of my two boys)*. Not appropriate here, imho, since what the writer really means is ***balance** two opposing forces*.

Answer (score 3):

"To even the keel" is a phrase I have never heard, and I doubt if it has existed before this.

I believe the writer is generalising from the phrase "to maintain an even keel", which is a sailing metaphor meaning "to keep the boat steady and upright". It seems to me that the writer means "bring the situation back to a state of balance".

Comment: This is clearly what is intended, but is it even possible (literally or metaphorically) to level something off in favour of one side?

Comment: @TimLymington: If the side in question was previously slighted by the unevenness, I don't see why it couldn't. Bringing things to even would favor the slighted side while not providing an advantage to either.

Comment: @Robusto The mixing of two notions of evenness (apparent fairness in the situation now obvious / compensation for past disadvantage) needs better explanation.

Comment: "Even the playing field" would have been a lot better idiom.

Comment: Googled "evening the keel".  About 55,000 results (0.38 seconds), and although some of these dealt with "evening" as a time of day, it's still a pretty common phrase.

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be a thing (nothing like 55k genuine examples though). The GloWbE corpus has precisely one instance of "even the keel", and none of "evening the keel".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the writer had too many metaphors in mind, beginning with the [Ship of State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_State) from Plato.

If the legal system systematically favors one group (employers) over an opposing group (workers), one might imagine the ship as [listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_list), or perhaps [tacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacking_(sailing)) in one direction more than another.

There's [a concept in law that is also called tacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacking_(law)). It's not quite the same thing, but perhaps the  maritime language has some hidden attraction for the legal mind (ropes fraying, etc.).

Anyway, if the ship of state is leaning to one side, it makes sense to **even the keel in favor of the side that is more deeply submerged**.

Answer (score 0):

"Even keel" is a term from the nautical world.  The keel is the central "backbone" of a ship's hull, running along the bottom from bow to stern.

An "even keel" implies that the ship is well-balanced -- the cargo and ballast on one side of the keel closely balances the cargo and ballast on the other side, so the ship rides upright rather than leaning to one side.

The term, and variants of it, is used in many common metaphors where "balance" is important, from describing mental stability to describing how a business is run.

While the quoted paragraph is not very clearly written, it's fairly easy to discern that "the state's unwillingness ... to even the keel" refers to a lack of effort/desire on the part of "the state" to take actions that would achieve (in the eyes of the author) "balance".  (Contrary to some comments, this is a fairly straightforward and "proper" application of "even keel" as a metaphor.)